# Invalid delivery method error when trying to add :confirmable to Users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, sendgrid, devise-confirmable

I added the confirmable attribute to User by following this github wiki
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

After that I want sendgrid server to send email confirmation link for that I added an addon in my heroku and do these changes to configure my environment.
In my config/environment.rb file I added the following code

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

In my development.rb file I added these two lines

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :text
config.action_mailer.default_url_options ={:host => 'http://localhost:3000'}
```

In my production.rb file I added these two lines

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options ={:host => 'finance-tracker-6.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'https'}
```

After doing all this.When I am signing up I am getting below error

```
RuntimeError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
Invalid delivery method :text
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [no such delivery method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration) as `text`. If you don't want to send SMTP emails in development, you can either use the `file` delivery method to get the emails saved in a file (it's also possible to [preview emails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails)), or use something like the [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener#letter-opener-) gem and set the delivery method to `letter_opener`. With this, emails get displayed in your default browser instead of actually getting sent.